# Visual Studio 2015 TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015 and I'm trying to use typescript.
I copied the example from typescript playground at:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

and I'm seeing the following warning: Expected '('.

this is the code:

```
<script>
    class Greeter {
        greeting: string;
        constructor(message: string) {
            this.greeting = message;
        }
        greet() {
            return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
        }
    }

    var greeter = new Greeter("world");

    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = "Say Hello";
    button.onclick = function() {
        alert(greeter.greet());
    }

    document.body.appendChild(button);
</script>
```

please help

Comment: I think I got it. You have to have inside a .ts file.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put TS directly in HTML.